# what happens when a negative integer is type cast to long in java?

Tags: java, integer, long-integer

```
int i = 0;

long ll = 0L;

i = -1 - 2; //  -3

i = (int) -1 - 2; // -3

ll = (long) - (int) -1 - 2;// -1

i = (int) +(long) -(int) -1 - 2;//-1

ll = (long) +(int) -1 - 2; // -3
```

In the above program at the line

```
 ll = (long) - (int) -1-2;
```

`ll` value is `-1`. How does its value becomes `-1` just by type casting? Shouldn't it be like 3 or -3?

Comment: The way you formatted your examples and output is very confusing. And although it is a bit hard to read, the best source for such information is the "Java langauge specification". In the long run, it is extremely helpful to turn to that document first, identify the corresponding section ... and figure out what is going on.

Comment: Can you share your research? What part of the language specification confused you in particular?

Comment: See [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/). A unary minus has the highest precedence of your operators, then the cast operator, _then_ the addition. `((long) (-((int) -(1)))) - 2`.So you cast `-1` to an `int`, you then apply unary minus to make `1`, you then cast `1` to a `long`, you then substract `2`. Putting spaces in some places in the hopes that that will reduce the precedence of those operations does't really work.

Comment: `ll = (long) + (int) -1 - 2;// -1`  will show -3 not -1

Comment: @prashant i have edited the line in the question.

Comment: @siva there will not be any difference if you are putting space in  between expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
i = (int) +(long) -(int) -1 - 2;
```

unary operator will be evaluated first then binary because of unary operator is higher precedence than binary operator.

so `-(int) -1` will be evaluated first and it will become `+1`

then `+(long)+1` will be `+1`

and after that `(int)+1` will be evaluated so it will become `+1`

then `+1-2` will be evaluated as `-1` so you are getting `-1`. same operation will be performed for other statements.